# Is the product of infinitely many valid kernel functions still a valid kernel function?

Tags: kernel-trick

I know it is true for product of two kernels. But I'm not sure if it is the case for infinitely many valid kernel functions. I tried to follow the proof for product of two kernels, but I don't know if I handled derivations related to infinitely many addends/multipliers correctly. So my question is:

First, is the claim true, i.e., is the product of infinitely many valid kernel functions still a valid kernel function?

Second, can you please offer a rigorous proof in which every step is guaranteed to be correct, preferably with a brief explanation or reference to some theorem, especially when rearranging infinitely many addends/multipliers. Thanks.

Comment: No the claim as stated is false. A simple counterexample are constant kernels where the product does not converge (as a sequence of real numbers).

Comment: @g g: You are right, because that would not be an inner product since the scalar field $\mathbb R$ does not contain $+\infty$. But what if the product is finite for all its variables?